# how to print date in input text box in html

Tags: javascript, html

here is my code,i want to print date in text box after enter date text using onload event.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <script>
         function displayDate() {
            document.getElementById("fname").value = Date();
         }
      </script>
   </head>
   <body onload="displayDate()">
      Enter date: <input type="date" id="fname" readonly />
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure you want an input of type="date"?  If it is going to be readonly, just use type="text".

Comment: An advantage of the date type input is that it's automatically formatted according to user's locale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to

- correctly create the `Date` object (you're missing `new`)
- format it according to [rfc3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339) (ex: `2012/12/30`)

Change

```
document.getElementById("fname").value = Date();
```

to

```
var now = new Date();
var formatedDate = now.getFullYear() + '-' + (now.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + now.getDate();​
document.getElementById("fname").value = formatedDate;
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/LPkPa/)

Note that some browsers accept other formats, but Chrome doesn't, as it complies to [the norm](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/datatypes.html#common.data.datetime-def).

Comment: how can i get the ' var formatDate = now.getFullYear() + '/' + (now.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + now.getDate();' into 'dd/mm/yyyy' format?

Answer (score 2):

The value attribute of the input box is a string, but your function is trying to assign a Date object.  You need to convert it to a string first.  Here's some code that will do it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <script>
         function displayDate() {
            var today=new Date();

            var date=today.toISOString().slice(0, -14);
            // Strip last 14 characters, ISO format is like
            // 2012-12-30T17:41:49.027Z but we want
            // 2012-12-30

            document.getElementById("fname").value=date;
         }
     </script>
   </head>
   <body onload="displayDate()">
      Enter date: <input type="date" id="fname" readonly>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function displayDate() {

   var now = new Date();

   var day = ("0" + now.getDate()).slice(-2);
   var month = ("0" + (now.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
   var today = now.getFullYear() + "-" + (month) + "-" + (day);

   document.getElementById("fname").value = today;
}​
```

Date control in HTML5 accepts in the format of *Year - month - day* while the `new Date()` in JavaScript returns date like eg: *Sun Dec 30 2012 10:09:05 GMT+0230*

See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Dez6U/)